# WebResource.axd not loaded when using latest Google Chrome Browser

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, dotnetnuke, webresource.axd

I'm having a strange issue:

I can't login at http://maskatel.info/login, when I try to click the login button (the blue button that says Connexion), nothing happens at all.

So I opened up the developer tools in Chrome (f12) and saw the following JavaScript error every time I click the button: `Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_PostBackOptions`

I then found out that this function should be in WebResource.axd, I then went to the Resources tab in the developers tool and found out that this 'file' is not there and it is not loaded in the HTML source.

I tried a lot of different things without any success and finally tried another browser and it works fine in any other browsers. That same page was working perfectly previously in Chrome on the same computer in the past.

So then I tried to click the small gear in the Chrome developer tools and went to the overrides section and changed the UserAgent to something else and refreshed the page and it works perfectly with any other UserAgent string. The correct  UserAgent when not overridden for my browser is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36`

So right now I really don't know what to do next:

- Is this issue related to the latest version of Chrome? I have not found any information on release dates for chrome.
- It could also be a DotNetNuke problem but I doubt it since nothing there changed before and after the problem
- It could also be asp.net related (I renamed App_Browsers to App_Browsers2 and still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh and I just noticed the same problem on the http://www.dnnsoftware.com website

Comment: What version of DNN are you using? I just tested with Chrome 28 and it works fine. I'm looking at upgrading to 29 now to test

Comment: I've definitely recreated this using Chrome 29 on your site and dnnsoftware.com, I'm going to run it up the DNNMVP flagpole and see if anyone knows what is going on.

Comment: It seams resolved on dnnsoftware.com if someone at DNN could let the communité know how it was resolved...

Comment: The version is 7.0.4 but after what I read, it looks like it appears even on version 6. Also I have tested it on my server with version 7.0.4 and the issue was not reproducible. So I'm pretty confident that it is hosting environment related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data file which addresses this issue is available to download from the following url.

http://51degrees.mobi/portals/0/downloads/51Degrees.mobi-Premium-20130823.dat

.NET users will need to perform the following steps.

1. Download the above data file.
2. Replace the file **51Degrees.mobi-Premium.dat**  in the App_Data folder of the web site with  the data file downloaded, renaming the downloaded data file to 51Degrees.mobi-Premium.dat
3. Restart the application pool servicing the web site to apply the new data file.

Some configurations may place the 51Degrees.mobi-Premium.dat file in a location other than App_Data. The web sites current location can be found in the 51Degrees.mobi.config file found in either the web site’s root folder or the App_Data folder. See the following page for more details.

https://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/NET/WebApplications/Config/Detection.aspx

Please use [contact us](https://51degrees.mobi/ContactUs.aspx) if you have any issues deploying this data file.

Answer (score 1):

We are having this problem on all our DNN6 sites at work (we can't update to DNN7 since we are stuck on SQL Server 2005 and Windows 2003 boxes). DNN support ticket response was:

"This is a known issue with the Google Chrome update to version 29, the browser is having many issues with ASP.Net pages. The current workaround is to use a different web browser until Google can release a new update."

but I know big asp.net sites like redbox and msdn.microsoft.com are working fine, so it's definitely not a global problem.

Our servers are patched by our infrastructure folks, and they are usually up to date (patched regularly), so not sure what specifically is the issue.

I have personal sites on DNN6 (3essentials hosting), that are working fine. So its definitely not all DNN6/7 sites that are having problems. Maybe its DNN6 sites that are running on Windows 2003 boxes?????

Comment: Can you confirm that you saw this issue on Asp.net sites that are not DNN sites? I would just like to make sure it is not DotNetNuke related.

Comment: And also, another workaround is to override the user agent string in chrome developer tools. The fact that just changing the user agent string fixes the issue is still puzzling for me but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone has found the culprit at google. It is related to 51degrees that reports a version 0 for Chrome 29 user-agent string.

More details at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277303

I tried to update the premium data (it is a professional edition installation) but I only get the same version that was aready there dating from 2013-08-15 and having 109 properties.

Then I tried renaming the App_Data/51Degrees.mobi-Premium.dat to add a .old at then end, but the system redownloads that file (same one looks like) to that directory.

So I went away and commented out the fiftyone configuration in the web.config file which instantly made the site work again for Chrome 29.

Let's hope there could be an update on a beter solution for this, but I think the culprit is finally found at least.

Comment: Commenting out 51 degrees will break other things, like mobile redirects or browser dependent code injections.

Comment: DNN Pro Support told me... "As long as your instance is connected to the internet, the file will update automatically. You will need to recycle the app pool and restart the application for it to apply properly.  You can also check the site bin folder. There should be a text file - 51Degrees.mobi.reset.txt - with todays date stamp." And that worked!

Answer (score -1):

On a DNN 7.1.0 site, that uses the Popup feature in DNN (login window opens in a modal popup) the login functionality appears to work fine.

I would recommend you try the Popup option, and if that doesn't work, look at upgrading to the latest release of DNN.

update: I tested the same 7.1.0 site using /login instead of the login popup and it also still works fine, so I would encourage you to look at upgrading your DNN instance.

Comment: I don't think it is related to the popups, but I just checked and the popups are activated on this website. It is using URLmaster though which changes domain.com?ctl=login to domain.com/login I think. I'll try upgrading to 7.1.0 tonight, we'll see if it fixes it. But I really have a fealing it is more about the hosting environment since that WebResource.axd link is generated by ASP.net under DNN. But I might be wrong.

Comment: It appears that it may be related to server updates, but I am not sure yet. Has your server had all the Windows updates applied that are available?

Comment: On my server yes, but the sites where I actualy have the issue are not under my control. I have asked the owner of that site where I first noticed the issue o check for update, which he will do tomorrow. We'll see.